# Improper integral: $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x \log|x- \pi|}{x(x-1)}dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

Can I get help determining the nature of this improper integral?

(¿Podrían ayudarme a determinar el carácter de está integral impropia?)

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x \log|x- \pi|}{x(x-1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is not an improper one since the integrand function $ f $ is not locally integrable at  $(0,+\infty)$.
You can speak only about
$$\int_0^1f$$
or
$$\int_1^{\pi}f$$
or
$$\int_{\pi}^{+\infty}f$$

Answer (score 0):

Show that
$$\int_1^{3/2}\frac{\sin x\log|x-\pi|}{x(x-1)}\,dx $$
diverges which would imply your integral diverges as well. Notice that the integrand is positive in $[1,3/2]$ and
$$\frac{\sin x\log|x-\pi|}{x(x-1)}\sim \frac{\sin(1)\log(\pi-1)}{x-1}\;\;(x\to 1^+) $$
So you need to show that
$$\sin(1)\log(\pi-1)\int_1^{3/2}\frac{1}{x-1}\,dx $$
is divergent.